# Which integers form the triangular grid?

Tags: geometry, number-theory, euclidean-geometry

Is there a set of integers (such as the Gaussian or Eisenstein integers) that define the regular triangular grid?

Comment: Maybe [Triangular Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)?

Comment: I genuinely have no idea what this question means. Can you be more precise?

Comment: No. 2 separate concepts.

Comment: Is there a rule or similar that defines the points in a triangular grid?

Comment: @diracdeltafunk Look up "triangular grid". The normal grid is a rectangular grid, where the intersection of the lines are 'lattice points' (i.e. integral in both arguments), OP asks about the points on a triangular grid?

Comment: Please see (and if possible respond to) the comment that I left, following Kaind's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(0,0)$ be the origin. Then any point on this grid has the form
$(h \cos (\frac{\pi}{3}) + k, h \sin (\frac{\pi}{3}) )  = (k + \frac{h}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{3} h}{2})$ where $h,k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

You can call these numbers whatever you like.

Comment: Unclear whether your answer represents the intent (who knows?) of the original poster (OP).  Excerpting: "Is there a set of integers (such as the Gaussian or Eisenstein integers) that define the regular triangular grid?".  One explanation is that the $y$-axis is presumed to form a $(60^\circ)$ angle with the $x$-axis, rather than $(90^\circ)$.  But then, the problem becomes trivial because every set of integers $(x,y)$ will be one of the lattice points on the grid.

Comment: Well there isn't one $y$-axis, there are actually $2$, one at $60$ and one at $120$ but this doesn't affect the points on the grid. I believe this is what the OP asks - recall that the Gaussian numbers are just those complex numbers with integral real and imaginary parts i.e. points on the grid. "Every set of integers will be lattice points on the grid" - uh no, if (0,0) is labelled the origin and triangle side is $1$, then you can check that $(0,1)$ can never be a lattice point.

Comment: Interesting take.  I thought of that, but I don't think that the idea of 3 axes, instead of 2 axes, is tenable in a 2 dimensional world.  Assuming only 2 axes, as I suggested, then each point is uniquely determined by its $(x,y)$ coordinates, which (to me) indicates that you can't have a third axis.  Assuming only 2 axes, then $(0,1)$ certainly is a lattice point.  It is part of the $(0,0), (0,1), (1,0)$ equilateral triangle.  Again, unclear what the OP's intent is.

Comment: Yeah the other axis, isn't use to represent another dimension, rather it's just shown as a line on the grid.

Comment: Your equilateral triangle has a right angle in it?

Comment: No, it doesn't.  Because the $y$-axis forms a $(60^\circ)$ angle with the $x$-axis.

Comment: Oh I see, your decomposing the points along this new oblique axis. I guess the OP's question was what would be these points in the original rectangular 2D coordinate system - else it's just a pair of integers.

Comment: Your interpretation would be fine, except that the $\sin(60^\circ)$ is an irrational number, so in the *normal* Cartesian coordinate system, you can't ever have the top of the triangle be a point $(x,y)$ where $y$ is an integer.  And the OP specifically referred to "...is there a set of integers...".

Comment: Yes his reference to "integers" confuses me now.. he should clarify.